# Python Print key of dictionarys (OrderedDict) within list withloop

Tags: python, python-3.x, ordereddictionary

I'm trying to figure out how to print a list, `storeItems`, that contains 3 `OrderedDict()`, and be able to print the `key` and `value` for each `OrderedDict`. I don't know how to solve this, and this is what I tried which gives me a `TypeError: string indices must be integers`.

```
storeItems = [{}, {}, {}]
storeItems[0] = OrderedDict()
storeItems[1] = OrderedDict()
storeItems[2] = OrderedDict()

storeItems[0]['Name'] = 'Auto-Enter'
storeItems[0]['Price'] = 30
storeItems[0]['Max'] = 100

storeItems[1]['Name'] = 'Multiplier'
storeItems[1]['Price'] = 100
storeItems[1]['Max'] = 5

storeItems[2]['Name'] = 'Factory'
storeItems[2]['Price'] = 100
storeItems[2]['Max'] = 3

#the original layout of the storeItems

#storeItems = [{
#        "Name": "Auto-Enter",
#        "Price": 30,
#        "Max": 100
#    }, {
#        "Name": "Multiplier",
#        "Price": 100,
#        "Max": 5
#    }, {
#        "Name": "Factory",
#        "Price": 200,
#        "Max": 3
#    }]
i = 0
for value in storeItems:
    for key in value:
        for i in range(0, 2):
            print(storeItems[i][key], storeItems[i][key][value])
```

## Things to note

I discovered doing `for value in storeItems: print(value)` will print `OrderedDict([('Name': 'Auto-Enter', ...)])` for each line. `print(storeItems[0]['Name'])` outputs `Auto-Enter`. I seem to struggle to make this into the loop.

I prefer for this to keep as close as you can to the original format of `storeItems`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each element in `storeItems` is a dictionary (`OrderedDict` is just a subclass that tracks the insertion order), so just loop over the [`dict.items()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values):

```
for odict in storeItems:
    for key, value in odict.items():
        print(key, value)
```